# Get Height Of View After Content Is Populated At Runtime

Tags: android, android-viewtreeobserver

I have a Cardview with height WRAP_CONTENT . Content of Cardview is to be populated after network call . And based on the height of Cardview  I have to set background in my fragment . So I tried using ViewTreeObserver and Post method but I am still getting value as 0.

```
cardTierInfo.post {
            cardTierInfoHeight = cardTierInfo.height
            setLayoutParams(cardTierInfoHeight)
        }
```

Call is being made in OncreateView.

Answer (score 0):

If you using kotlin extends `core-ktx` it is easy to get actual height by `doOnLayout`

```
cardTierInfo.doOnLayout {
            cardTierInfoHeight = cardTierInfo.height
            setLayoutParams(cardTierInfoHeight)
}
```